# Recursively update table rows based on select from ALL_TABLES in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that contains table_name and value of ID column of all tables in a schema and I want to set the value according to the max value of ID column in each table.

So far I have a function to get max(id) from a table:

```
create or replace function get_max_id ( t_name in varchar2 )
return number as max_id number default null;
begin 
execute immediate 
    'select max(id) from ' || t_name into max_id;
return max_id;
end;
```

And the following select returns me all table names and max(id) values:

```
select TABLE_NAME, GET_MAX_ID( owner || '.' || table_name ) max_id
from ALL_TABLES at
where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
and at.TABLE_NAME in (
    select eks.NAME from SCHEMA_NAME.ENTITY_KEYS eks
)
```

But I'm struggling to update `ENTITY_KEYS` table with the max_id value.

This doesn't work obviously (getting `single row subquery returns more than one row`):

```
update SCHEMA_NAME.ENTITY_KEYS eks
set eks.CUR_VALUE = (
    select GET_MAX_ID( owner || '.' || table_name ) max_id
    from ALL_TABLES t
    where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
    and eks.NAME in (
        select name from SCHEMA_NAME.ENTITY_KEYS
        where NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
    )
)
;
```

How can I change the above update statement to update each row recursively or update the select to return only one row?

Tried with a join and naturally getting the same error:

```
update SCHEMA_NAME.ENTITY_KEYS
set CUR_VALUE = (
    select GET_MAX_ID( owner || '.' || table_name )
    from SCHEMA_NAME.ENTITY_KEYs eks
    inner join ALL_TABLES t on t.TABLE_NAME = eks.NAME
    where t.owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
)
;
```

Comment: Are you sure all the tables have the same column "Id" ? Any particular reason to have this design? What's the use of storing the max value of an id in a table when the values are bound to change? I believe a better approach to the problem you're trying to solve exists.

Comment: Yes, all tables have the `ID` column. The `ENTITY_KEYS` is supposed to be updated with the latest value each time a new record is inserted, so in essence `ENTITY_KEYS.CUR_VALUE` should match with the `max(ID)` of each table. But there are discrepancies in the test env which I want to fix and I don't want to do this manually as there are hundreds of tables.

Comment: *"The ENTITY_KEYS is supposed to be updated with the latest value each time a new record is inserted"* - That can be achieved using a trigger(even if u could avoid mutating table errors) on all tables which is not advisable.

Comment: I'm not trying to fix the design or the system :) What I want to do is fix the `ENTITY_KEYS` table in one of the testing environments that has incorrect data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the direct function in the update table statement:

```
UPDATE SCHEMA_NAME.ENTITY_KEYS EKS
SET
    EKS.CUR_VALUE = GET_MAX_ID('SCHEMA_NAME'
                               || '.'
                               || EKS.NAME)
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            ALL_TABLES T
        WHERE
            T.TABLE_NAME = EKS.NAME
            AND T.OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
    );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This doesn't work really. I'm getting `table of view does not exist USERNAME.GET_MAX_ID`

Comment: ok so you need to pass only tables which exist. then the use of all_tables is needed. Let me re-frame my answer